# Weird font displaying problem -- Maybe index out of bounds?

Tags: c, rendering, osdev

Screenshot of the rendering system attempting to display `"ABCD1234!\n"`:

[image]

(text size is very small, so I had to crop in quite a bit so it's visible)

The characters displayed are not in the font array, so it seems to me like I've indexed something out of bounds somewhere. Here's the relevant code:

```
// I've left out a bit of initilization code, the rest of the code is in the Github repository 
// linked, at bootloader/include/bootloader_tty.h


size_t strlen(const char * _str)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    while(_str[i++]);
    return i - 1;
}

// Prints character 'c' at X, Y
void terminal_putc(char c, unsigned int x, unsigned int y, uint32_t fgcolor)
{
    for (unsigned int Y = 0; Y < 8; Y++)
    {
        for (unsigned int X = 0; X < 8; X++)
        {
            if ((font[(c * 8) + Y] & (1 << X)))
            {
                *((uint32_t*)(framebuffer_addr + 4 * pitch * Y + y + 4 * X + x)) = fgcolor;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Writes the string `data` of length `length` to the "terminal"
void terminal_write(const char* data, size_t length)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        char c = data[i];

        if (c == '\n')
        {
            cursorY++;
            break;
        }

        terminal_putc(c, cursorX * 8, cursorY * 8, 0xFFFFFFFF);

        cursorX++;

        if (cursorX > consoleWidth)
        {
            cursorX = 0;
            cursorY++;
        }
    }
    
}

// Writes the string `data` to the "terminal"
void terminal_writestring(const char* data)
{
    terminal_write(data, strlen(data));
}
```

The way I'm calling `terminal_writestring()` is:

```
terminal_writestring("ABCD1234!\n");
```

Github repository: [link](https://github.com/ThatCodingGuy86/UnnamedOS-V2)

Answer (score 0):

### The distortion exists for a couple of reasons

1. The leftmost pixel for any character resides in bit 7 of the concerned font byte. Your code currently fetches it from bit 0, thereby mirroring the output of the character.

   Change `if ((font[(c * 8) + Y] & (1 << X)))` into either

   - ```
     if ((font[(c * 8) + Y] & (1 << (7 - X))))
     ```

   or

   - ```
     if ((font[(c * 8) + Y] & (0b10000000 >> X)))
     ```
2. The offset address calculation only scales the character-internal (X,Y) offsets, but forgets to also scale the (x,y) screen coordinates.

   Change `*((uint32_t*)(framebuffer_addr + 4 * pitch * Y + y + 4 * X + x)) = fgcolor;` into

   - ```
     *((uint32_t*)(framebuffer_addr + 4 * pitch * (Y + y) + 4 * (X + x))) = fgcolor;
     ```

Comment: I'd completely forgotten about this question. I fixed both of those issues, although the first I fixed somewhat accidentally, by a mistake in the way I convert my font image to a C array (some very janky Python code) that ended up mirroring them anyways. I don't want to touch that mess of spaghetti, so I'll just leave it as is.